# Is it possible to lower the priority of a request mapping to come at the very end of the path checking in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have the following method which handles all requests which do not match another path.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**")
public void doUrlRequest(final HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
```

However, it is being called for paths like `/css/style.css` and `/images/logo.png` causing them not to load. Is it possible to push it to a lower priority so that it is the last path that is matched? I need to handle requests like `/tag/channel`.

In Rails, this would be equivalent to moving the path to the bottom of `routes.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

Its never a good idea to use `/**` to handle your requests. Use specific handler methods to mark them with `@RequestMapping` Moreover static resources are needed to be handled using static resource handlers. In your configuration class that extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, you need to add handlers for such resources. Here is an example of such a file:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfigurations extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] CLASSPATH = {"classpath:/static/"};

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
        if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/**")) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                    .addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH);
        }
    }
}
```

This configuration assumes that your static resources are being served from `resources/static` directory.

**EDIT:**
As you mentioned in the comment that you would like to handle requests like `/tag1/channel1` etc, a nice way to do this would be to use path variables. Following annotation should do the trick:
`@RequestMapping("/{tag}/{channel}")` and use `String` based arguments in the controller method. Here is a sample:

```
@RequestMapping("/{tag}/{channel}")
public String usefulMethodName(@PathVariable String tag, @PathVariable String channel) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I added that but it doesn't work. The request is still being handled by the controller. `$ curl -i http://127.0.0.1:8080/css/style.css
HTTP/1.1 302
Location: http://127.0.0.1:8080/pageNotFound`

Comment: Can you please describe the directory structure from where the static resources are being served.

Comment: `ls src/main/resources/static` => `ls target/project-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/static/`

Comment: Have you removed the `@RequestMapping("/**")` annotation from your application? If possible, can you please provide a link to github.

Comment: I don't want to remove `@RequestMapping("/**")`. I said in the question `I need to handle requests like /tag/channel`. So I need one method to handle `/tag1/channel1`, `/tag1/channel2`, `/tag2/channel1`, etc. I want the controller method to be the last match to test.